# How to create a Dynamic input fields on button click using anuglar js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, input-type-file

I have a dropdown menu like this

[image]

[ShortAnswer- TextBox,Checkbox,Radio button and Drop down]
User can choose the input type and there can add the options by clicking the add option button like this 
[image]

by clicking the cross icon the options need to be removed.

I reffered [dynamic text area](http://plnkr.co/edit/n4BKHFWG0HnmhZ4rBjG5?p=preview)

```
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamic-add-textbox-input-button-radio-element-html-javascript/
```

But I need more reference about this, Please Suggest me an idea to achieve this using angular js.

Comment: Had worked before on something similar. For adding drag-drop support, you can use ng-sortable (https://github.com/a5hik/ng-sortable)

Answer (score 1):

Build your list of inputs from an array of objects that each define an input. On button click add a new object to the array that defines the input you want to add.

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="input in inputsList">
  <span ng-click="remove($index)>x</span><input ng-if="input.type==='text'" type="text" />
  <span ng-click="remove($index)>x</span><input ng-if="input.type==='checkbox'" type="checkbox" />
  ...
</div>
<button ng-click="addNewCheckBox()">Add</button>
```

controller:

```
$scope.addNewCheckBox = function() {
  $scope.inputsList.push({ type: 'checkbox' });
};

$scope.remove = function(index) {
   $scope.inputsList.splice(index, 1);
};
```

It would probably be best if you had a custom input directive that took a config object and it would decide which input to build. But for the sake of simplicity and clarity I just used basic raw html inputs.

Let me know if that makes sense or you need an Angular2/4 answer.